# Query hangs with larger tables in MS-Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Hyper V,
2008 R2
Access 2010
Number of Records: Table 1, 162,769 linked to Table 2, 40,2262

MS Access hangs and goes not responding until it locks.  The query is as follows:

```
SELECT [Civil Aircraft Registry].[Common Name], [Civil Aircraft Registry].Model, 
    [Linked History Total WO Costs].LastOfPRT, [Linked History Total WO Costs].LastOfUNT, 
    [Linked History Total WO Costs].LastOfSVP, [Civil Aircraft Registry].registration, 
    [Linked History Total WO Costs].ARG

FROM [Civil Aircraft Registry], [Linked History Total WO Costs]

WHERE (((Right([Civil Aircraft Registry].[registration],3)) 
        = Right([Linked History Total WO Costs].[ARG],3)));
```

The query works in smaller doses but not with the large record size.

Any help would be appreciated.

Jeff

Comment: Is [Linked History Total WO Costs] a query?

Answer (score 4):

The `Right` functions in your join condition (in your case, the WHERE clause) are causing the Access Database Engine to do repeated table scans. So, for 162,000 rows * 40,000 rows you're effectively trying to do ~6.5 Billion (6.5E+9) row comparisons.

You'll probably have to create a separate `Text(3)` field in each table, populate them with `Right( ... , 3)` from the existing `Text` fields, index them, and then join the two tables on those new fields.

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to avoid functions in your `WHERE` clause, it does reduce performance.

When the function is in the `WHERE` clause, it is called for every record in the result set which can slow down your query performance. Doing this will also prevent the use of any index on the column.

You can create a calculated column instead:

```
SELECT [Civil Aircraft Registry].[Common Name], [Civil Aircraft Registry].Model, 
    [Linked History Total WO Costs].LastOfPRT, [Linked History Total WO Costs].LastOfUNT, 
    [Linked History Total WO Costs].LastOfSVP, [Civil Aircraft Registry].registration, 
    [Linked History Total WO Costs].ARG, right([Civil Aircraft Registration],3) AS Reg_3,
    right([Linked History Total WO Costs].ARG,3) AS Arg_3

FROM [Civil Aircraft Registry], [Linked History Total WO Costs]

WHERE Reg_3 = Arg_3;
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your help.  I am going to try both methods and let you know how they work.  Thanks again.